# How to cast &u8 to usize

Tags: casting, rust

I'm working on some coding challenges in Rust and one of the problems is to determine if a phrase is a pangram. I have seen the following implementation:

```
// Copy chars into a vector, sort and remove duplicates
let mut chars: Vec<char> = pangram.chars().collect();
chars.sort();
chars.dedup();
```

This solution, however, is `O(nlogn)` time because of the sort. I can do it in `O(n)` time, but I'm running into a problem.

Below is the code I've tried to write:

```
fn is_pangram(s: String) -> bool {
    let mut num_seen = 0;
    let mut seen: [bool; 26] = [false; 26];

    for c in s.to_lowercase().as_bytes() {
        // ASCII 10 is newline character
        if c as usize == 10 {
            break;
        }

        // Lowercase ASCII is 97 to 122
        if !seen[122 - c as usize] {
            seen[122 - c as usize] = true;
            num_seen += 1;
        }
    }
    return num_seen == 26;
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

> 18:55 $ rustc pangram.rs
>
> pangram.rs:10:12: 10:22 error: casting `&u8` as `usize` is invalid
>
> pangram.rs:10         if c as usize == 10 {
>   pangram.rs:10:12: 10:22 help: cast through a raw pointer first
>
> pangram.rs:14:24: 14:34 error: casting `&u8` as `usize` is invalid
>
> pangram.rs:14         if !seen[122 - c as usize] {
>   pangram.rs:14:24: 14:34 help: cast through a raw pointer first
>
> pangram.rs:15:24: 15:34 error: casting `&u8` as `usize` is invalid
>
> pangram.rs:15             seen[122 - c as usize] = true;
>
> pangram.rs:15:24: 15:34 help: cast through a raw pointer first
>
> error: aborting due to 3 previous errors

I've tried casting `c as *mut usize` and `c as *const usize`, but neither worked. How many I make this work?

Comment: Get rid of the comment and write `if c == '\n' as u8 { break; }` instead.

Comment: @Veedrac Thanks for the suggestion. I changed that line to account for all punctuation, whitespaces, etc. It is now `if c > 122 || c < 97 { continue; }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a very simple change—a single character, in fact:

```
    for &c in s.to_lowercase().as_bytes() {
        ^
```

You're trying to treat a *reference* (which is what `as_bytes` results in) as a regular value, which doesn't work.

You could either do what I did above (change `for c in` to `for &c in`) or replace all occurrences of `c` inside of the `for` loop with `*c`; they essentially do the same thing.